# Connect Array to Google Chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json, google-visualization

I've been trying for ages to try and connect this array to a google chart and having no luck, would really appreciate some help to locate what I've done wrong. I have a jsfiddle going, and you can see that the array is fine, if copied and pasted to the chart manually it works, so it's just a code issue of not making it through.

http://jsfiddle.net/DNH5n/8/

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var dataset =     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://data.sparkfun.com/output/AJ2p4r8Owvt1MyV8q9MV.json?page=1',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (jsonObj) {
            var arr = ["[['Time', 'Humidity', 'Temp']"];
            $.each(jsonObj, function (i, tObj) {
                arr.push("['" + tObj.stationtime + "', " + tObj.humidity + ', ' + tObj.temp + ']');

            });
            arr.push("]")

            // This for debugging
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;
        }
    });
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        dataset
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You can't use an AJAX call as the input to arrayToDataTable. You have to use the result of the AJAX call.
2. Parse the output of the AJAX call, and put them into Date objects, and floats.

Check out the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/K8bk3/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://data.sparkfun.com/output/AJ2p4r8Owvt1MyV8q9MV.json?page=1',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (jsonObj) {
        var arr = [['Time', 'Humidity', 'Temp']];
        $.each(jsonObj, function (i, tObj) {
            arr.push([new Date(tObj.stationtime),  parseFloat(tObj.humidity), parseFloat(tObj.temp)]);

        });
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;
    var  data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);

var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance'
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, was trying for hours! I'm pretty green when it comes to AJAX, jQuery, JSON & Javascript. I also sent an email to Phant who provide the database/logging system and they kindly did this up too http://phant.io/graphing/google/2014/07/07/graphing-data/

Comment: Thought I'd post what I ended up with for now, uses an Annotation Chart which is handy for selecting the date range. Thanks again!
http://jsfiddle.net/K8bk3/